# Symbolic link error to Java / LIBJVM

Tags: java, openjdk, postgresql, symbolic-link

All,

When trying to install postgresql, I get the following error:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jamvm/libjvm.so is not a symbolic link
```

I think this is bad...but thought I'd reach out in case there was a way to fix it.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Ubuntu 12.04